# Running random operations over vector, conditional

Tags: r, random

I am doing some modelling and wish to simulate randomness.

I have a total number of runs `run_times` which is `5` in this example. 
A vector holding `run_lengths` will print `1`'s for which, so if run length is 3, it prints `1`'s 3 times. 
The `sample_data` includes a sample of `1`'s and `0`'s. The application of printing `1`'s along a `run_lengths` is randomly done when `sample_data == 1`; not all `== 1` is to be picked though. Only random... and operation can only print `1` for a total number of `run_times` (5).

Theres a few moving parts for sure.

I am tackling the problem in this manner:

I am able to select `run_lengths` at random with `sample(run_lengths, 1)`. I am unsure how to select `sample_data` at random and I'm trying to keep a counter in order to stay under `run_times`:

```
run_lengths <- c(2,4,5,6,7,8,1)
run_times <- 5
sample_data <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
# Randomly select 1's from sample_data, when find 1, randomly print 1's along run_lengths 
# Only print a certain amount of times (run_times)
# Pick run_lengths at random == sample(run_lengths,1)
# Pick df$sample 1's at random, how to randomly select????

count <- 0  # keep track of how many random run_lengths is being applied
res <- NULL
while (length(res) < length(sample_data)) {
   if (sample_data[length(res)+1] == 1 & count < run_times) { # not sure how to pick sample_date == 1?
   res <- c(res, rep(1,sample(run_lengths,1)))   # if signal == 1 (randomly) then randomly rep a run_length
   count <- count +1  # count how many random reps, run_lengths have been applied
   } else {
     res <- c(res, 0)  # Note if condition is not true, we print 0 vs 1
   }
}
res <- res[1:length(sample_data)]
res
```

I have completed it maybe on 60%? I'm not sure what is the best approach for choosing random `1`'s from sample_data. Also I'm not sure how to only keep number of `run_lengths` under the `run_times` maximum. I am attempting to keep a `count` for when the condition was true. If it was exceeded, it would ignore any other true conditions.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what do you want - too many questions asked. If you asked how to fill vector `sampled_data` with 0s and 1s, use binomial distribution with 1 trial (aka bernoulli). `sampled_data <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)`

Comment: Basically randomly select existing 1s in sample_data. On random ==1 selection of sample_data. Perform printing of 1s for lengths of run_lengths. The total number of the above operation can not exceed run_times.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, time to put down some code, still not sure about if it's right or not

```
sample_data <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)

# take indices of of sampled data where value == 1
i <- which(sample_data %in% 1)

# now shuffle them all, no replacement - random positions with 1s
p <- sample(i, length(i), replace=FALSE)

print(sample_data[p[1]])
print(sample_data[p[2]])
print(sample_data[p[3]])
...
```

Is this what you want?